# Angular 2: Routerlink not working in header component

Tags: angular

I have a RC5 app with the following setup:

main.ts:

```
// Dynamic (JIT) compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// Our main app module
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, routing, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ErrorComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

shared.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [TranslatePipe, DateToStringPipe, HeaderComponent],
    exports: [TranslatePipe, DateToStringPipe, CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HeaderComponent]
})

export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {

        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                FeedbackService,
                CookieService,
                AuthService,
                LoggerService,
                RouteGuard,
                {
                  provide: TranslateLoader,
                  useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json'),
                  deps: [Http]
                },
                TranslateService,
                SearchService,
                SharedComponent,
                HeaderComponent
            ]
        };

    }

}

@NgModule({
    exports: [SharedModule],
    providers: []
})
export class SharedRootModule {}
```

I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to show each module in the application and it works fine.

But I can't use "routerlink" inside my `HeaderComponent`. If I move the markup to my `AppComponent` it works, so there is no markup problem.

All other components that gets loaded inside the `<router-outlet>` can use "routerlink".

What am I doing wrong with the `HeaderComponent` ?

Comment: Probably need to see the code for your HeaderComponent to work out whats going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RouterLink does not belong to CommonModule but belongs to Angular's RouterModule you must import that module before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks! Importing `RouterModule` in the SharedModule solved the problem.